# Checkbox dinâmico com Ajax e PHP

Tags: php, ajax, checkbox, div

Estou gerando uma div de produto com php, nesta lista eu gostaria de acrescentar um check-box com valor booleano 0-1 para ativo e desativo. Quando o gerente clicar em desativado o produto não apareça para o usuário, não consigo achar um exemplo sobre isso para quando clicar no check-box o Ajax mande o valor para PHP.
Segue abaixo o código PHP para a geração da div ao consultar.

```
               $result_produto = "SELECT * FROM produto";
        $resultado_produto = mysqli_query($conn, $result_produto);
        while($row_produto = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_produto)){

            echo "<div class='row border bg-color: #80006f'>" . "<div class='col-2 p-3 '>" . "<img class='Img rounded border border-primary'  src='". $pasta . $row_produto['Img_produto'] . "'id='produto''>" . "</div>"
                . "<div class='col-5>'" . "<div class='row'>" . "<span class='name-prod'> Nome: </span>" . $row_produto['Nome_produto'] .
                "<div class='row'>" ."<span class='desc-prod-title'> Descrição:</span>" . $row_produto['Descricao_produto'] . "</div>" . "</div>".
                 "<div class='col-2>'" . "<span class='price-prod'> Preço: </span>" . $row_produto['Preco_produto'] . "</div>" . "</div>";   
        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do lado do cliente (browser) é com JavaScript que pode disparar novas requisições web e então executar outro script PHP que atualize as informações no seu banco de dados.

[Introdução à AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) é um bom começo para compreender isso bem.

Seu código deve ser algo parecido com isso:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.status-check-input').on('click', function() {
    let id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    let enabled = $(this).is(':checked');
    console.log(id);
    console.log(enabled);
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://example.org/php/file/update/status.php",
      method: "POST",
      dataType: "applicatin/json",
      data: {
        "id": id,
        "enabled": enabled
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row border bg-color: #80006f">
  <div class="col-2">
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="32" class="status-check-input">
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <img class='Img rounded border border-primary'  src="/path/to/folder/product_image.jpg" id="32">
  </div>
  <div class="col-8">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <span class="name-prod">Nome:</span> Um Produto
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class="col">
          <span class='desc-prod-title'>Descrição:</span> Apenas um produto de teste
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <span class="price-prod">Preço:</span> R$ 42,31
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Perceba que eu trabalhei com apenas a saída de um produto explicitamente escrito com HTML e considerei o id do produto como `32`. Sua listagem de produtos deve produzir um resultado parecido com esse.

E, minha requisição AJAX retornará erro porque o destino no campo `url` não é o correto, você tem que alterar para o seu caso, mas vimos no console o `id` do produto e o status do campo checkbox na variável `enabled`.

Agora que tem o jQuery enviando seus dados via AJAX, para pegar os valores no PHP:

```php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
print_r($data);
/** Saída
Array
(
    [id] => 32
    [enabled] => 1
)
*/
```

Comment: Muito obrigado isso vai me ajudar muito, no meu caso eu só comecei fazendo     var check = document.getElementsByName($row_produto['ID']); para o name ser igual ao ID do banco, e achei que pudesse pegar pelo ID, o valor da tabela ativado, assim poder alterar ela